# Log in screen on first start

Tags: android, password-protection, apk

how would you create an activity that only runs when the application is started for the first time ever and provides the user with a screen to input a pin and "unlock" the application

---

First time ever meaning when the application is first installed and started for the first time. As in the `FIRST EVER` time it is opened.

Answer (score 1):

You can use android preferences for show login screen only for the first time.

You can set flag in preference and check it when application start.

Answer (score 0):

By "application starting for the first time ever" I am assuming you mean the first time an `Activity` appears on the display.

I usually test for the existence of a user preferences database. If it does not exist, then the application has not ever been active, and then I could prompt the user for a configuration update.

Look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html) for a `PreferenceManager` to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can always start with something like "splash screen" activity, that will only check in database/ shared preferences if user is logged in. Then you can run login activity or not.
Or in first activity you can show popup window with request of login.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sharedPreferences`:

```
boolean firstTime = prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", true);
if(firstTime) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
    editor.commit();

    //do your first time "operations" here E.G read configuration, show user guide
}
```